# How can I generate an incrementing Billing number that contains text codes?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, winforms

I have a billing form in my Winform app. I want to increment the bill number automatically upon billing. I have a new button to clear everything and start a fresh billing. so i created a code in that buttons click event.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Bill_No FROM POS order by Bill_No Desc", con);
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            int b = a + 1;
            string Bill = "Bill";
            txt_BillNo.Text = Bill+b.ToString();
```

Now problem is When i click that button for the second time i. 'a' gets varchar data. Like Bill12. For the next click i want to increment as Bill13. But as it gets data from database as varchar it cant increment number alone. So is there any way to get the number from the varchar ? like 12 from bill12?

Comment: Are you familiar with auto increment of SQL Server?

Comment: I need to follow a pattern. So iam adding "Bill" string infront of number. But it gets stored as varchar. I have a main id column which is auto increment.

Comment: You can use the Substring method to skip _"Bill"_ : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Abhijith putting any kind of business logic in a key is a VERY SERIOUS design bug. How are you going to use that key value in SQL? How are you going to perform JOINs with it if you have to parse it every time? If you want something to be a bill, use a separate field, eg `DocumentType` and store the type in there. Better yet, create a `DocumentTypes` table and store the correct ID in your `DocumentTypeId` field

Comment: R u telling i have to create a seperate table for bill no?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: as far as I can see, Abhijith is trying to implement a sequential billing number with a fixed (??) prefix - this really isn't a key & seems reasonable to me - though there could be better implementations & I wouldn't expect Auto increment to be used for this.

Comment: @Abhijith I'm telling you that you should properly design your database schema. Avoiding business logic in the key is Rule #1 - it violates the 1st Normal Form. You just saw one of the problems caused when you violate that rule.

Comment: @PaulF if this is a billing number, there would be no need to *parse* it afterwards

Comment: Billno is only a column which is unique.. not my primary key.

Comment: @Abhijith why are you trying to extract the number then? That's a clear indication that the field is trying to do two things at the same time

Comment: Instead of autonumbering, or trying to parse older billing numbers, use a T-SQL [SEQUENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) to issue incrementing billing numbers, eg : `CREATE SEQUENCE BillingNoSeq START WITH 1  INCREMENT BY 1 ;` and read the next value each time you want a new billing number `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR BillingNoSeq;`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos.. I have a form. there is a textbox named bill_No. so when the billing person takes that form that textbox should display the highest number from bill_no+1.And when he print button the new value will be stored in database. When he press new button again that highest number from bill_no +1 will display in textbox. but if i follow a pattern like "BILL12" rather than just number i cant increment the value as "Bill12" will gets stores as varchar instead of int. so no use in incrementing a varchar.

Comment: @Abhijith *don't* do it this way. Either store the numeric part of the invoice number separately or use a SEQUENCE for this. *Don't* try to use `MAX+1` either - you'll end up with **duplicate invoice numbers** if two users open the same form

Comment: @Abhijith which version of SQL Server are you using? `SEQUENCE` is available in all supported versions, ie 2012 and later but some people are still using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: sql server 2012. Do i have to drop my current table? i want that sequence in my textbox when i click new and when i click 'print' it should be saved in my database. again when i press new i want a new sequence.. so on.

Comment: No, you don't. You can execute a separate query to get the next value from the SEQUENCE, format the string any way you want and store it to the text field. If you need the numeric part for other reasons, you should store it in an additional field.

Comment: @Abhijith be aware that `SEQUENCE` numbers are generated outside the current transaction. Rolling back won't decrease the sequence, which makes perfect sense - if Client 2 issues the bill 1002 you wouldn't want a rollback by `Client 1` to decrease toe sequence to 1000.

Comment: If you need to do this crazy thing, use TWO columns for your "counting": One for the names "Bill", "Charly" or whatever the names will be, an a number column .... then use SELECT MAX(..) with the appropriate where clause to find the next number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex for identifying integer from string.\d+ is the regex for an integer number. So

```
 //System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex

 resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value;
 returns a string containing the first occurrence of a number in subjectString.

 Int32.Parse(resultString) will then give you the number.
```

Comment: Or simply *don't* try to store any kind of business logic in the key. Using a regex to extract the actual key number is an ugly hack. The key shouldn't contain logic. A regex may cover up the problem in a very limited scenario, when presenting a record. The key will still be unusable for joining, filtering etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use stuff to replace Prefix, that will give you numeric value

```
Select STUFF('Bill1',1,4,'')
```